# Does converting from bytearray to bytes incur a copy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-internals

Does converting from the mutable `bytearray` type to the non-mutable `bytes` type incur a copy? Is there any cost associated with it, or does the interpreter just treat it as an immutable byte sequence, like casting a `char*` to a `const char* const` in C++?

```
ba = bytearray()
ba.extend("some big long string".encode('utf-8'))

# Is this conversion free or expensive?
write_bytes(bytes(ba))
```

Does this differ between Python 3 where `bytes` is its own type and Python 2.7 where `bytes` is just an alias for `str`?

Comment: All operations involve *some* cost. You could look at the source, or you can use timing tests to see if the time increases linearly with the problem size (as would happen if a copy was made).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that converting `bytearray` to `bytes` incurs a copy. This is because if the new `bytes` points to the same backing array as the `bytearray`, then it wouldn't be truly immutable.

Comment: Note that if you want a view on the contents of a `bytearray` without making a copy, you _can_ use a `memoryview` for the purpose. The caveat is that changes to the `bytearray` data will change the data in the `memoryview`, and that the `bytearray` cannot be resized (no `append`s, `pop`s, resizing slice assignments, etc.) for as long as any exported buffers (of which `memoryview` is the most common type created in Python level code) exist.

Comment: In Python 2 you can also use `buffer()` to make a read-only buffer out of a `bytearray` without actually performing a copy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A new copy is created, the buffer is not shared between the `bytesarray` and the new `bytes` object, in either Python 2 or 3.

You couldn't share it, as the `bytesarray` object could still be referenced elsewhere and mutate the value.

For the details, see the [`bytesobject.c` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/bytesobject.c#l3257), where the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) is used to create a straight up copy of the data (via [`PyBuffer_ToContiguous()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/memoryobject.c#l970)).

Answer (score 9):

Martjin is right. I just wanted to back that answer up with the cpython source.

Looking at the source for bytes [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytesobject.c), first `bytes_new` is called, which will call `PyBytes_FromObject`, which will call `_PyBytes_FromBuffer`, which creates a new bytes object and calls `PyBuffer_ToContiguous` (defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/memoryobject.c)). This calls `buffer_to_contiguous`, which is a memory copy function. The comment for the function reads:

> Copy src to a contiguous representation. order is one of 'C', 'F' (Fortran) or 'A' (Any). Assumptions: src has PyBUF_FULL information, src->ndim >= 1, len(mem) == src->len.

Thus, a call to bytes with a bytearray argument will copy the data.