# casting a bytes sequence to a bytearray sequence without copying the data?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pointers, casting

I was wondering: is possible to convert a `bytes` object into a `bytearray` without copying the data, ensuring that they point to the same area in memory?

Unfortunately just using `bytearray` will allocate and copy the bytes:

```
In [22]: foo1 = b'foobar'

In [23]: foo2 = bytearray(foo1)

In [24]: foo2[3] = 122

In [25]: foo2
Out[25]: bytearray(b'foozar')

In [26]: foo1
Out[26]: b'foobar'
```

I need this because a function called from a library written in C is returning a `bytes` object (likely not copied), while I would like to modify that data and there doesn't seem to be other options.

any idea?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880065/does-converting-from-bytearray-to-bytes-incur-a-copy

Comment: @danielfranca : it's not a duplicate, it's a different question. I know the answer to the question you are referring to. I need a way to circumvent that fact.

Comment: as bytes is an immutable data I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: You cannot circumvent it. How could Python allow the memory assigned to an immutable object now be part of a mutable one? That breaks the immutability.